# Why is the app name under /data/app different from that under /data/data?

Tags: installation

After I installed DiskInfo.apk through `adb install DiskInfo.apk`, under /data/app, there is an installed apk named:

**me.kuder.diskinfo.pro-1.apk**

However, under /data/data, there is a new directory named:

**me.kuder.diskinfo.pro**

Why is the apk name under /data/app appended with "-1"?

And why is the name under /data/app different from that under /data/data?

Comment: I would guess it's due to Android supporting multi users, and that the number indicates the user ID (aka "1" for owner), but I don't have proof, and haven't researched about it. Other than that, the name is the same though.

Comment: @AndrewT. +1. But why is the folder under /data/data not appended the "-1"?

Comment: Yes sounds good what Andrew is writing. I could also guess that this -1 is related to the installed version of this apk. Maybe if you install a newer version when this version is still installed it's number will increase. The folder in /data/data is always named after the package chosen for this apk, read from its AndroidManifest.xml file so it does not contain this -1 thingy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .apk file can be named whatever you want. It doesn't have to be named even anything related to the application ID.

In this case, what happened is that, when the file was downloaded, there was probably already a `me.kuder.diskinfo.pro.apk` in the download directory (or perhaps a temp directory), so the OS added "-1" to the filename. The contents, however, weren't changed, so the app still registers itself without the "-1".